# How to obtain a "sure"-statement from an "a.s."-statement?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

**Setting** We work on a filtered probability space with finite time horizon $T$. The filtration is assumed to be complete. Let $X$ be a stochastic process that satisfies a property (A) a.s. For example, if property (A) is being nonnegative at the time $T$, then $X$ satisfies $P[X_T \geq 0]=1$.

**Question** I would like to obtain that $X$ (up to indistinguishability) satisfies property (A) *for each* $\omega$.

**My attempt** Define a process $Y$ to be equal to $0$ on the event $\{X_T <0\}$ and define it to be equal to $X$ on $\{X_T \geq 0\}$. Then $Y_T \geq 0$. Is it then correct that $X,Y$ are indistinguishable, i.e. $P[X_t=Y_t, \forall t\in[0,T]]=1$? Is this approach possible whenever the event where the stochastic process does not satisfy the desired propert has probability $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you modify $X$ only at time T over an event of 0 mass, yes all that happens strictly before T is equal to $X$ for every $\omega$ and only for the path which are negative at time T you have to modify your process so yes $X$ and $Y$ are indistinguishable.
Formally :
$$\Omega = \{X_t=Y_t, \forall t\in[0,T]\}\cup \{X_t\not=Y_t, \forall t\in[0,T]\}$$
$$=\{X_T=Y_T\}\cup \{X_T\not=Y_T\}$$

So as $P[X_T=Y_T]=1=P[X_t=Y_t, \forall t\in[0,T]]$

Comment: Thank you. What about the following example: I know that $\sup_{t\in [0,T]} |X_t|<\infty$ a.s. Can I then define $Y$ as $Y=X$ on the event $\{\sup_{t\in [0,T]} |X_t|<\infty\}$ of probability $1$ and $Y=X$ on the complementary event of probability $0$? Are $X,Y$ then indistinguishable?

Comment: sorry but there must be a typo in your example Y=X both on event A and its complementary set.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $Y=0$ on the complementary event.

Comment: The situation is different here because you don't know when the infinity values are "touched" by $X$ even though the event is of null mass so it's random times. I am not sure if those are indistinguishable. My gut tell me it shouldn't be the case but Ican't think of a proper counterexample. Probably one toying with $\Omega= [0,T]$ and processes functions of $t$ might be of some utility, where at only one point X take infinity for a given path but no path are equal on the interval [0,T].

Comment: Are $X,Y$ at least versions, i.e. for each $t$, $P[X_t=Y_t]=1$?